# Integrate new relic with go swagger

Tags: go, swagger, newrelic, go-swagger

In golang we have used go swagger to generate a bunch of APIs, now we trying to integrate new relic with our application, trying to wrap around the API to get the metrics, can it be done through yaml file or any other way? Because refactoring every API would not be ideal

I couldn’t find any references from the official websites

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at opentelemtry?

https://opentelemetry.io/registry/instrumentation-go-net-http/

You could use the new relic exporter.